# jquery phone number validation with "match" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on validating the phone number  using jquery in the format of:

```
+XX-XXXX-XXXX
+XX.XXXX.XXXX
+XX XXXX XXXX
```

However,it is giving me an error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

```js
function phonenumber(inputtxt) {
 var phoneno = /^\+?([0-9]{2})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{4})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
 if(inputtxt.value.match(phoneno)) {
  return true;
    }  
 else {  
   alert("message");
   return false;
    }
  }
 jQuery(".btnchec").click(function(){
  var inputtxt = jQuery("#inputcpf").val();
  console.log(phonenumber(inputtxt));
  });
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Validation</legend>
  <div style= "padding-top:15px;">
   <label style= "padding: 20px; font-size: 16px; font-weight:600; color: #AA6903;">ID: </label>
   <input type="text" id="inputcpf" name="cpf" size="18" maxlength="18" autofocus>
    <input type="button" style= "margin-top:10px;" class="btnchec" name="Submit" value="Check">
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2):

inputtxt is a string and therefor does not have a .value property.

Change:

```
if(inputtxt.value.match(phoneno))
```

TO:

```
if(inputtxt.match(phoneno))
```

Comment: @Molly try this if your regex isn't working. This one seems to work. I did minimal testing. http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/3aar5L7x/